# Keyboard iOS (Chrome) Hide input with position absolute

Tags: ios, css

I have a component that displays an input text box

```
<div class='container'>
    <input type="text" />
</div>
```

My style is :

```
.container {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 100;
}
```

The behavior is only on iOS (Chrome) when I click on the input text, the keyboard opens and hides the input text.

IMG 1: input at bottom and keyboard close

IMG 2: With keyboard Open

[image]

I want the input text to stay on the screen so that I can see what I am entering.

The same problem occurs with twitter mobile on inbox chat.

Thanks

Comment: Does manually adding a border via css help?

Comment: Not working same error